# sales data / JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a sales data for a couple of years in an array:
var= ['Jan-2019',325678], ['feb-2019', 456789], ['Mar-2019',-12890],.....['Dec-2021', 987460]

1 -want to calculate the net total amount of profit/losses over the entire period.
2- Average of the (changes) in profit/losses over the entire period - track the total change in profits from month to month and find the average(total/number of months)
3 - greatest increase in profit (month and amount)over the whole period
4 - greatest decrease3in profit (month and amount)over the whole period

Tried to solve number 1 using :
`

```
const profitMonths = data.filter(el => el[1] > 0);
console.log("Total:", profitMonths.map(el => el[1]).reduce((a, b) => a + b));
console.log;
```

`
but the sum I am getting is different from what excel and calculator is giving me.
I will appreciate some help here

Comment: Please add an actual input, because what you put in the question is invalid format

Comment: it is more like : VAR data=[['Jan-2019', 325678], ['Feb-2019',  456789], ['Mar-2019',- 12890]];

Comment: Can you provide an explaination for the data provided? It appears to be a month and then what I'm assuming are the profits for that month? Or is the number value something else like change in profits?

Comment: it is the amount of sales, positive number when profit is made and negative when that month made a loss: ,['May-2018', 158620],['Jun-2018', 87795],['Jul-2018', 423389],['Aug-2018', 840723],['Sep-2018', -568529],['Oct-2018', -332067],['Nov-2018', 989499],

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I've made the necessary updates to my answer/code and it should cover the 4 pieces of data you requested using a single `.reduce()` call.

Comment: Numbers still dont match, only getting correct the length and the total. bit not the average and the rest.

Comment: I added some additional notes to my post that break down and outline the results, but based on the input/example data given, my `.reduce()` produces the exact results you would get if calculated manually. So if you are getting something different I'm curious how you are applying the code to your data, or what sort of discrepancies you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is the format of your original `data` records for each of the months. I assumed that your `data` format is like below. But you could get the sum of each months growth or loss (earnings) like this and also get what you were trying as well (profit months total sales):

```js
const data = [
  ['Jan-2019', 325678],
  ['Feb-2019', 456789],
  ['Mar-2019', -12890],
];

const earningsArray = data.map((el) => el[1]);

const profitMonths = data.filter((el) => el[1] > 0);
const salesOnProfitMonths = profitMonths
  .map((el) => el[1])
  .reduce((accVal, curVal) => accVal + curVal, 0);

const avgOfProfitAndLoss =
  earningsArray.reduce((accVal, curVal) => accVal + curVal, 0) / data.length; // get the average of all total and losses

const maxMonth = {
  monthName: '',
  profit: 0,
};

const minMonth = {
  monthName: '',
  profit: 0,
};

data.forEach((month) => {
  if (month[1] > maxMonth.profit) {
    maxMonth.monthName = month[0];
    maxMonth.profit = month[1];
  }

  if (month[1] < minMonth.profit) {
    minMonth.monthName = month[0];
    minMonth.profit = month[1];
  }

  return { maxMonth, minMonth };
});

console.log('Total sale of profit months: ', salesOnProfitMonths);
console.log('Total average : ', avgOfProfitAndLoss);
console.log('The month with max profit is : ', maxMonth);
console.log('The month with min profit is : ', minMonth);
```

Comment: This has definitely gave me the exact sum I am getting on my spread sheet. Thanks so much. do you know how I could solve the rest?

Comment: Hey, glad I could help, I just updated my response to solve rest of the question.

Comment: Thanks for that, just tried you code in regards to average I am after the Average of "Changes" in profit and loss over the whole period(it is more of tracking the changes from month to month and then find the average of the change not "total average". also not the month with MAx profit but the month that has the most or the greatest increase . Same for losses not the month with most losses but the month that had the greatest decrease compared to other months.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.reduce()` you can actually build an object to the returned based on all of the data from your original array.

```js
const data = [['Jan-2019', 325678], ['feb-2019', 456789], ['Mar-2019',-12890], ['Dec-2021', 987460]]

let result = data.reduce((a, b, i) => {
    let d = (i > 1) ? a : {total: a[1], average: a[1], sumChange: 0, lastMonth: a[1], increase: a, decrease: a},
        change = b[1] - d.lastMonth
    
    d.total += b[1]
    d.sumChange += change
    d.lastMonth = b[1]
    d.average = d.sumChange / i
    d.increase = (d.increase[1] > change) ? d.increase : [b[0], change]
    d.decrease = (d.decrease[1] < change) ? d.decrease : [b[0], change]
    return d
})

console.log(result) // Return the full object
console.log(result.total) // Only return one value, the total
```

Based on the array/input you provided, this should provide a net total, average profit/loss, highest increase from the previous month, and highest decrease from the previous month.

#### EDIT

I had to make a few adjustments after getting some clarification. But this again should return a single object that holds values for everything requested by OP. (*the **sumChange** and **lastMonth** values are only there to help with the `.reduce()` function month over month*)

#### NOTES

Just for clarity as OP claimed they were not getting the right values, here is a breakdown based on the provided data:

| Date | Sales | Change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-2019 | $325,678 | N/A |
| Feb-2019 | $456,789 | $131,111 |
| Mar-2019 | -$12,890 | -$469,679 |
| Dec-2021 | $987,460 | $1,000,350 |

Based on this input, calculated manually:

The "***Average of the (changes) in profit/losses over the entire period***" is $220,594 (***($131,111 + $469,679 + $1,000,350) / 3***).

The "***greatest increase in profit (month and amount)over the whole period***" would be Dec-2021 with a $1,000,350 increase.

And the "***greatest decrease in profit (month and amount)over the whole period***" would be Mar-2019 with -$469,679.

This is exactly what my `.reduce()` does produce, so I'm not sure what actual input or output OP is getting (or how they are applying this to their code/data).